# Laravel collection merge from array based on item key value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I have an array of `$dates` like below

```
[
    "2022-30",
    "2022-31",
    "2022-32",
    "2022-33",
    "2022-34",
    "2022-35",
]
```

and I have a `$collection` with an output like below

```
[
    {
        "new": 60,
        "settled": "1",
        "date": "2022-31"
    },
    {
        "new": 50,
        "settled": "1",
        "date": "2022-32"
    },
]
```

how can I achieve a result like below which merge the value of `date` from the $collection item if it matches from the date on `$dates` array

```
[
    {
        "new": 0,
        "settled": "0",
        "date": "2022-30"
    },
    {
        "new": 60,
        "settled": "1",
        "date": "2022-31"
    },
    {
        "new": 50,
        "settled": "1",
        "date": "2022-32"
    },
    {
        "new": 0,
        "settled": "0",
        "date": "2022-33"
    },
    {
        "new": 0,
        "settled": "0",
        "date": "2022-34"
    },
    {
        "new": 0,
        "settled": "0",
        "date": "2022-35"
    }
]
```

I tried making the dates into a collection and formatting the output like the `$collection` format and use `merge` but this just combine the two collection together with duplicates.

```
$out = collect($dates)->map( function($d, $k)  {
    return [
        'new' => 0,
        'settled' => 0,
        'date' => $d
    ];
});

return $out->merge($collection);
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dates = [
    "2022-30",
    "2022-31",
    "2022-32",
    "2022-33",
    "2022-34",
    "2022-35",
];

$collection = collect([
    [
        "new" => 60,
        "settled" => "1",
        "date" => "2022-31"
    ],
    [
        "new" => 50,
        "settled" => "1",
        "date" => "2022-32"
    ]
]);

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    if (!$collection->where('date', $date)->count()) {
        $collection->push([
                'new' => 0,
                'settled' => 0,
                'date' => $date
        ]);
    }
}

return $collection->sortBy('date')->values()->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can key the collection by dates and then add in the dates that are not in there:

```
$out = $collection->keyBy('date')
$out = $out->merge(
    collect($dates)
        ->whereNotIn(null, $out->keys())
        ->mapWithKeys(fn ($date) => [
            $date => [
                'new' => 0,
                'settled' => 0,
                'date' => $date
            ]
        ])
)->sortKeys()->values();
```

What this does is convert the collection to one that has the dates as keys, then filters from dates all the dates that are already in the collection, maps the rest into your desired format, sorts them all to how they should be then discards the keys.

Comment: your code produces an error, it lacks a single close parenthesis and if I add one, it says
`Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::whereNotIn(),`

can you format it a bit cleaner, Im confuse the way you call the `merge` and `whereNotIn`

Comment: @SymmetricsWeb I've updated the code. It needed the "key" parameter

Answer (score 0):

For the $dates maybe you can filter only the dates that does not exist in the collections? Then after you can map them out and merge.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).